# How do I normalize labels using tf.data?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to build a regression model using Keras. Because I have a lot of data that cannot be loaded in memory, I am using tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset to create a dataset object.

The data needs to be normalized, and I think I understood how to normalize the features, but I can't find a proper way to normalize the labels.

I have the following code so far, with my training data being in csv files in the `training_data` folder. In the csv files, columns `'a'` and `'b'`are the features, and `'labels'` are the labels, all numeric.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten

# Create the dataset
dataset = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
    file_pattern = "training_data/*.csv",
    select_columns=['a', 'b', 'labels'], 
    label_name='labels',
    batch_size=5, num_epochs=1,
    num_parallel_reads=20,
    shuffle_buffer_size=10000)

# Create a function for feature normalization
def get_normalization_layer(name, dataset):
    # Create a Normalization layer for our feature.
    normalizer = preprocessing.Normalization()

    # Prepare a Dataset that only yields our feature.
    feature_ds = dataset.map(lambda x, y: x[name])

    # Learn the statistics of the data.
    normalizer.adapt(feature_ds)

    return normalizer

# Create a preprocessing layer for input
numerical_columns = []
for feature in ['a', 'b']:
    normalizer = get_normalization_layer(feature, dataset)
    num_col = tf.feature_column.numeric_column(feature, normalizer_fn=normalizer)
    numerical_columns.append(num_col)

preprocessing_layer = tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures(numerical_columns)

# Create and compile the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(preprocessing_layer)
model.add(Dense(20, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(20, activation='relu'))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mse'])
```

So in short, how do I normalize labels in a `PrefetchDataset`?

Comment: Why don't you normalize them the exact same way you are normalizing the features?

Comment: I don't know how. As I understand it, the normalization is done on the fly by the preprocessing layer. I am not sure how to tell the model to normalize labels during training.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following, you can use the `from_generator` API for normalizing the labels. If you want you can normalize your features also with this approach. I am providing a pseudo code as I don't have your complete code with me, but you will get the gist of where I am going.

```
def gen():
  # initialize enumerator
  dataset_enum = dataset.enumerate()
  i = 0
  x = []
  y = []
  for element in dataset_enum.as_numpy_iterator():
    # I am supposing that element[0] is x and element[1] is y.
    if i % BATCH_SIZE == 0:
      # normalize y
      normalized_y = normalization_function(y)
      x_features = x
      x = []
      y = []
      yield x_features, normalized_y
      
    x.append(element[0])
    y.append(element[1])


new_dataset = tf.data.Dataaset.from_generator(
    gen,
    output_signature=(
        # here what you expect to have as an output.
        # Look at this to have a better idea https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_generator
    )
)
```

Feel free to ask questions.

Comment: Ok, that's exactly what I'm looking for, thanks a lot. I realised that there is a problem though, which is that I need to de-normalise the output to have a prediction afterwards, but I don't have a normalisation function to do that. Any thought about this? Shall I try to normalise the labels beforehand then?

Answer (score 0):

This may seem a bit unorthodox but you could make use of the multiply and add layer to reverse the normalization.

If you were using the functional api you would just add the two layers at the end:

```
x = multiply([x, np.sqrt(normalizer.variance)])
x = add([x, normalizer.mean])
```